# Al consumir una API va acumulando valores

Tags: python, json, flask

estoy desarrollando una API para consumir información de una tabla de SQL Server, el tema es que cada vez que recarga el sitio, las peticiones se van sumando.. esta es mi consulta y mi función:

```
def qClients():
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS')
    for row in cursor:
        rows.append({"id" : row[0], "name" : row[1], "surname" : row[2], "phone" : row[3]})
    
    return rows


@app.route('/api/clients')
def getClients():
    list = qClients()
    return jsonify({"clients" : list})
```

Seguramente es una tontería, pero es mi primer backend, gracias!

Comment: `rows` es una variable global?

Comment: Parece que `rows` es una variable global, aunque no la has declarado como tal en tu función y te debería de dar un error de referencia. Por favor agrega todo el código

Comment: Efectivamente, al estar la variable global era lo que me repetía los datos! error de noob, muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Christian Una función puede usar una variable global sin declararla, eso no dará ningún error con tal de que la variable esté definida (tenga un valor) en el momento en que se vaya a acceder a ella.

Comment: `return [{"id" : row[0], "name" : row[1], "surname" : row[2], "phone" : row[3]} for row in cursor]` te elimina la necesidad de la variable `rows` (ni global ni local) y por tanto desaparece el problema.

Comment: @abulafia me acabo de acordar las funciones si tienen acceso a las demás variables >_<  (otro error de noob(?))

Comment: @Christian Te habrás liado, y es comprensible, con el asunto de que si una función asigna algo a una variable (no declarada) que ya existía como global, se creará una local con el mismo nombre en vez de acceder a la global. Seguramente para evitar caer en este problema te habrás acostumbrado a declararlas siempre como global.